# Need to create an external facing form that accepts multiple rows and then the response is sent to a sharepoint List

Tags: sql, list, forms, sharepoint, webforms

My organization currently uses an excel sheet for student signups. We need to create an external facing form. This form will have predefined columns and we would like the user to be able to add rows dynamically (in case they have multiple students to signup). The user would submit the form and then the results would populate a sharepoint list.

We've looked at powerapps but it looks like we need a user license to use the app and that would be prohibitively expensive. We are new to the sharepoint/365 environment. What ideas do you all have?